# Using relative positioning with Python 3.5 and pandas

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pandas

I am formatting some csv files, and I need to add columns that use other columns for arithmetic. Like in Excel, `B3 = sum(A1:A3)/3`, then `B4 = sum(A2:A4)/3`. I've looked up relative indexes and haven't found what I'm Trying to do.

```
def formula_columns(csv_list, dir_env):
    for file in csv_list:
        df = pd.read_csv(dir_env + file)
        avg_12(df)
        print(df[10:20])

# Create AVG(12) Column
def avg_12 ( df ):
    df[ 'AVG(12)' ] = df[ 'Price' ]
    # Right Here I want to set each value of 'AVG(12)' to equal
    # the sum of the value of price from its own index plus the
    # previous 11 indexes
    df.loc[:10, 'AVG(12)'] = 0
```

I would imagine this to be a common task, I would assume I'm looking in the wrong places. If anyone has some advice I would appreciate it, Thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be done with the rolling method:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 5, 10), columns = ['A'])

df
Out[151]: 
   A
0  2
1  4
2  1
3  1
4  4
5  2
6  4
7  2
8  4
9  1
```

Take the averages of A1:A3, A2:A4 etc:

```
df.rolling(3).mean()
Out[152]: 
          A
0       NaN
1       NaN
2  2.333333
3  2.000000
4  2.000000
5  2.333333
6  3.333333
7  2.666667
8  3.333333
9  2.333333
```

It requires pandas 18. For earlier versions, use `pd.rolling_mean()`:

```
pd.rolling_mean(df['A'], 3)
```

Comment: That solution worked for this particular example. What if i want `B3 = A2` `B4 = A3`?

Comment: Use shift for that: `df['B'] = df['A'].shift(1)`

Comment: Thank You! I guess i need to spend sometime looking at DataFrame functions.